# Jest Vue Test - Can't test window.scrollTo fn()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

Have a simple scroll to Element function utilizing `getBoundingClientRect` & `window.scrollTo`, but can't get any iteration of the Jest test to get any coverage beyond `branch: 100`. All other test coverage is at 0.

Function to be tested:

```
export default function scrollToEl(el) {
  let elRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return window.scrollTo(
    elRect.left + document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    elRect.top + document.documentElement.scrollTop
  );
}
```

Jest test that doesn't provide 100% coverage in all categories:

```
import * as scroll from "../scrollToEl";

describe("scrollToEl test", () => {
  let element;
  let ev = jest.fn();
  scroll.scrollToEl = jest.fn(() => {
    ev;
  });
  beforeEach(() => {
    element = document.createElement("div");
  });
  it("should be called", () => {
    ev(element)
    expect(ev).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

How do I get full 100% coverage across the board?
Help please.

**EDIT - now with 100% coverage across the board:**
[image]

JS function:

I had to alter the `export default function` to `export const scrollToEl = function (el)`

```
export const scrollToEl = function (el) {
  // ...
};
```

Test:

I had to simplify the test to get 100% coverage across the board. I added and checked for `window.scrollTo` along with calling the actual function on newly created element `(el)`.

```
import * as scroll from "../scrollToEl";

describe("scrollToEl test", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
  });
  it("`window.scrollTo` should be called", () => {
    const el = document.createElement("span");
    scroll.scrollToEl(el);
    expect(window.scrollTo).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first I have an issue with your goal of wanting 100% code coverage. But this isn’t a question about that, so we’ll skip over that for now.

To get Jest to not complain about `scrollTo`, you have to mock it.

```
window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
```